# Error: installting GDB-8.1 with target=mips-elf-linux

Tags: gdb, ubuntu-16.04, reverse-engineering, mips32

Below error occurs while installing gdb-8.1 on Ubuntu-16.04-TLS with target configuration>> `--target=mips-elf-linux`:

```
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd/po'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/.../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/.../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/.../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd'
Makefile:1748: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/.../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd'
Makefile:1885: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/.../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be/bfd'
Makefile:2756: recipe for target 'install-bfd' failed
make[1]: *** [install-bfd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/.../gdb-installation/gdb-8.1-mips32be'
Makefile:2223: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Kindly help me fix this!

Comment: The actual error is somewhere earlier in the log.